# ubuntu 16.10 RTL8723BE can't login after reinstall of the driver kernel 4.8.0-34

Tags: network-manager, 16.10, rtl8723be

From the first day I got my laptop I face problems with WiFi but I was able to fix it with commands provided [here](https://chirath02.wordpress.com/2016/05/12/installing-realtek-rtl8723be-driver-for-ubuntu-16-04/).

Usually when I restart my computer and an update was installed I need to redo them.

Ihis time it didn't work and when I retried again, it kept hanging so I closed the terminal and everything started to get slow so I restarted which was faster than normal but the WiFi still not working and when I tried to restart once again I couldn't pass the logging page!

When dropping to the terminal any command that uses `sudo` just freeze the computer even `sudo nano`

When I use reboot, it takes so much time to restart so I have to use the power button.

I managed to use the computer by booting to 4.8.0-32-generic instead of 4.8.0-34 and I see it asks me to update but I just ignored it.

[Here](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipMRaUBwa_WJo0DkZKabyGbl_0oxfw9lF7VDu6MqYjcQf9qYLzD4O6mAJBnaHeXU7Q?key=aU9xaGEyamduM2FzUW5fWXhEa2Q5c1drSmNqLXR3) are images that I captured login, sudo nano and trying to restart

[image]

[image]

Any ideas on what happened in kernel 4.8.0-34-generic??

Comment: The problem is not related to the wireless driver.

Comment: what do u suggest ??

Answer (score 0):

Boot with the 4.8.0-32 kernel, remove your old wifi driver and download the newest Realtek driver from github:

```
sudo apt-get purge rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
sudo apt-get install build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
```

Now reboot and boot with the 4.8.0-34 kernel and try these steps:

Step 1: Install the driver:

```
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

Step 2: Find the strongest signal

Now you should detect which antenna receives the strongest signal. Repeat the following commands to find it: Replace XXX with 0, 1 or 2

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=XXX
iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|level'
```

The latest command will show an output similar to this one:

```
enp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

                    Quality=24/70  Signal level=-86 dBm  
                    ESSID:"YOUR WLAN NAME"
```

Obliviously this received signal is too weak(Quality=24/70) so in this case you should check the other antenna. Remember to run all of the three commands that's mentioned in the step 2.

Note: More than one antenna may receive a signal but you should pick the one that receives the strongest signal from you modem.

Step 3: Config your wifi

Run the following command to config your wifi, replace xxx with the found antenna number.

```
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=XXX" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

If you still haven't connected to your wifi then:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

If not again then:

```
sudo reboot
```

Finally read these references if this solution wasn't helpul:

https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/reserve-7
http://www.linuxlinx.com/2016/07/another-solution-how-to-fix-realtek.html
http://www.linuxlinx.com/2016/05/install-realtek-rtl8723be-wifi-driver-ubuntu-linuxmint.html

**The alternative solution:**

If you can't solve your problem then I think you have only one option, removing 4.8.0-32 kernel and letting Ubuntu 16.10 boot with the old kernel. For removing the new kernel you must boot with the old kernel so you will not have problem with sudo anymore.

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.8.0-34-generic
```

Don't worry about downgrading your kernel because you always can install it manually again.

You can also test another version of kernel and see if your system works  with it or not. Download its source from here: https://www.kernel.org

BTW version 5.0.0 is releasing in the mid of 2017 and you can give it a try as well.

Comment: as I said sudo commands are stuck and thats almost what  I do everytime , however I gave it a try and didn't work (over 40 minutes waitng for sudo make install)

Comment: I am sorry that the solution didn't help and waste your time. I provided an alternative solution. Hope it helps.

Comment: I already set grub to load a linux-image-4.8.0-32-generic kernel but I'm interesting in knowing what is the problem to begin with

Comment: Do you have HWE kernel installed? If yes try to remove it and put nonHWE one. I had simmilar issues with it